# Material UI Drawer component adding unwanted shadow when not focused

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, z-index

I'm having some issues using the `Material UI` `Drawer` component. When I try to display it in my webpage it tries to force the focus to the inner `div` and adds a shadow or border to the component if you're focused anywhere else.

Does anyone know what's causing this shadow to appear and how to disable it? Example screenshot below - you'll see a blue edge at the bottom (this is the same all the way round if I resize the element)

As soon as you click on content inside the `Drawer` e.g. a `List` element the shadow goes away. I assume it must be something to do with the component being modal?

```
<Drawer PaperProps={{ className: classes.floatingMenu }} anchor='top' open onClose={() => {}}>
    <div className={classes.dummy}>
    </div>
</Drawer>
```

Note: The `floatingMenu` class only adds a margin at the top of `55px` (i.e. the height of the `AppBar` - nothing else).

[image]

Comment: It seems like you want to be using `variant="persistent"` (https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer) rather than `variant="temporary"` (the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue in a little more simplistic manner after reading the doc's a bit more. On the `Modal` [page](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/) it states:

> Notice that you can disable the outline (often blue or gold) with the
>   outline: 0 CSS property.

Based on this I didn't touch the component or inner components from my question but instead I simply added one extra CSS class `outline: 0` to `floatingMenu` (which is already passed to the `PaperProps`):

```
floatingMenu: {
    marginTop: '55px',
    outline: 0
}
```

This resolved the problem and I no longer see the blue shadow border.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat tricky, but possible with just some props and styling. The element that is shading the rest of the UI is the `Backdrop` component of the `Modal` component. `Drawer` uses `Modal` when it's in temporary mode. The `hideBackdrop` prop of the `Modal` controls whether the shade is seen or not, and you can pass this prop to the `Drawer` directly as well.

However, the `Modal` component itself would still cover the whole viewport, preventing you from clicking other areas of the UI, before the `Drawer` is closed. I'm not sure if there's a simpler way, but at least you can do it by just using CSS styling to make the `Modal` element "through-clickable" by setting its `pointer-events` to `none`. To restore the "clickability" of the drawer itself, you should then set its `pointer-events` back to `all`.

So, for instance, just using the `style` prop to make simple inline styling:

```
<Drawer hideBackdrop style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
  <div style={{ pointerEvents: 'all' }}>
    I'm a sidebar!
  </div>
</Drawer>
```

[A working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-brook-rlxnb)

If you twiddle with Material UI's styling solution, you could also pass the `pointer-events` style rule to the `Drawer`'s own `Paper` through the `classes` prop.